# Trying to update value of a new column in python

Tags: python, pandas

```
def Old_new(df):
    """Identify if a car is old or new"""
    for x in df.index:
        if df.iloc[x]['Last Odometer Reading'] < 100:
            df.iloc[x]['Status'] = 'New'
        else:
            df.iloc[x]['Status'] = 'Old'
    return(df)
```

the function above marks the status of the car as new if odometer reading is below 100. However it doesn't seem to work

```
df.iloc[x]['Status'] = 'New'
```

seems to have a issue.

However, using

```
df.loc[df['Last Odometer Reading']<100, 'Status'] = 'New'
```

works well.
Can someone tell me why?

Comment: Is there an error? If so, please post the full error message with the traceback in the question.

Comment: <ipython-input-263-aebb0c94d609>:10: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
  df.iloc[x]['Status'] = 0
<ipython-input-263-aebb0c94d609>:8: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
  df.iloc[x]['Status'] = 1

Comment: This is the warning I am getting.

Comment: However it does not update the Status column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`df.loc[df['Last Odometer Reading']<100]` is a Dataframe and therefore you can add a new column by using brackets.

`df.iloc[x]` is a Series and doesn't allow this, it behaves more like a list.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I understood where i was wrong. Ishould have used iloc instead. Thanks a lot

Comment: @at_514 If you are satisfied with the answer, accept it. Please read: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)